# Is it possible to make pointy buttons (apple like) with CSS3?

Tags: forms, css

I want to make a button like the **iPhone back button just with CSS3**.

Is it possible? How?

You can see my objective [here](http://cl.ly/2B291W0Q3j2P401K3L2s):

[image: iPhone back button]

Comment: This is my favourite implementation: [http://cssdeck.com/labs/one-tag-ios-like-buttons](http://cssdeck.com/labs/one-tag-ios-like-buttons)

Answer (score 17):

This is one possible solution, using primarily CSS2 (with just a touch of optional CSS3 for border-radius and box-shadow). This is a limited, straightforward solution that seems to work in current versions (as of Nov 2012) of Chrome and Firefox, and likewise renders nearly identically in IE7-9. I don't have IE10 to test, but one can reasonably assume it is fine.

I wrote "limited" because these buttons must use solid background-colors in order to render identically across browsers. Also, the box-shadow does not fully extend to the "point," but used sparingly it may not be objectionable. Box-shadow is optional anyway, since it is unsupported on old IE unless augmented with something like [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

http://jsfiddle.net/yHprm/11/

```css
.wiz-buttons > a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font: normal 14px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wiz-buttons > a > .button {
  min-width: 75px;
}
/* Next Button */

.wiz-buttons > .next {
  color: #FFF;
}
.wiz-buttons > .next > .arrow-inner {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 3px;
  z-index: 2000;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 14px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #E38A13;
}
.wiz-buttons > .next > .arrow {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #CC790B;
}
.wiz-buttons > .next > .button {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #E38A13;
  border: 2px solid #CC790B;
  border-right: 0;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 9px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.wiz-buttons > .next:hover > .arrow {
  border-left-color: #ad6608;
}
.wiz-buttons > .next:hover > .arrow-inner {
  border-left-color: #CC790B;
}
.wiz-buttons > .next:hover > .button {
  background-color: #CC790B;
  border-color: #b66c09;
}
/* Previous Button */

.wiz-buttons > .previous {
  color: #666;
}
.wiz-buttons > .previous > .arrow-inner {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 3px;
  z-index: 2000;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 14px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.wiz-buttons > .previous > .arrow {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #e8e8e8;
}
.wiz-buttons > .previous > .button {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  border: 2px solid #eaeaea;
  border-left: 0;
  padding: 3px 9px 3px 3px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.wiz-buttons > .previous:hover > .arrow {
  border-right-color: #e1e1e1;
}
.wiz-buttons > .previous:hover > .arrow-inner {
  border-right-color: #eaeaea;
}
.wiz-buttons > .previous:hover > .button {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border-color: #e3e3e3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wiz-buttons">
  <a class="previous" href="#">
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    <span class="arrow-inner"></span>
    <span class="button">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="next" href="#">
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    <span class="arrow-inner"></span>
    <span class="button">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: Here is a blog post explaining how the arrow is achieved with borders. This is why you cannot have a gradient. It's a hack so ruled it out as a solution for me. http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/11/22/css-quick-tip-css-arrows-and-shapes-without-markup/

Comment: Add "border-left: 0px;" To the following tags to remove the excessive left padding of the previous arrow 

.wiz-buttons > .previous > .arrow-inner
.wiz-buttons > .previous > .arrow

And "" for the pad on the next

Add "border-right: 0px;" for nextarrow 

.wiz-buttons > .next > .arrow-inner
.wiz-buttons > .next > .arrow

Answer (score 9):

Here is example output:

[image: iOS style back buttons with CSS3]

http://jsfiddle.net/stowball/XvFFX/

### **HTML**

```
<h2>iOS style back buttons with CSS3</h2>
<div>
    <a href="#"><span>Back</span></a>
</div>
```

### **CSS**

```
div {
    background: #000;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
}

a {
    background: #950006;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #de0009 0%, #950006 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #de0009 0%, #950006 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #de0009), color-stop(100%, #950006));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #de0009 0%, #950006 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #de0009 0%, #950006 100%);
    border: solid #dd0009;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    padding: 0 7px 0 3px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:before {
    background: #950006;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #de0009 0%, #950006 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #de0009 0%, #950006 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #de0009), color-stop(100%, #950006));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #de0009 0%, #950006 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #de0009 0%, #950006 100%);
    border: solid #dd0009;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
    border-radius: 2px 0 2px 2px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 21px;
    left: -11px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 21px;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
    border-color: #b50007;
    background: #7e0004;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b50007 0%, #7e0004 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b50007 0%, #7e0004 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #b50007), color-stop(100%, #7e0004));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b50007 0%, #7e0004 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #b50007 0%, #7e0004 100%);
}

a:hover:before, a:focus:before {
    border-color: #b50007;
    background: #7e0004;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #b50007 0%, #7e0004 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #b50007 0%, #7e0004 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #b50007), color-stop(100%, #7e0004));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #b50007 0%, #7e0004 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #b50007 0%, #7e0004 100%);
}

a span {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Very nice idea, but shame the colour gradients do not work properly on recent Chrome and IE :( Time to switch to a flat theme! :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can do this making a [CSS arrow](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/11/22/css-quick-tip-css-arrows-and-shapes-without-markup/)

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/t5C4p/

HTML

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    <span class="button">button</span>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.arrow {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border:  15px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #000;
}

.button {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: I wish the OP would have chosen an answer, but this method worked best for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fiddle I made with a "skew" (to make the arrow part slimmer) and a pointy tip, to make it even more iOS like:

(Removed jsfiddle link due to new guidelines)

---

### Update

**A Blogpost about creating iOS5 or iOS6 style arrow buttons**

[Blogpost](http://cssnerd.com/2013/03/09/ios-6-arrow-button-pure-css-html/)

Comment: advanced version http://dream-world.us/2011/11/30/the-best-pure-css3-ios-style-arrow-back-button/

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/stowball/XvFFX/